# Firecuda SSHD What actually happens to the files?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage

I apologise if I am posting incorrectly but I just ordered a Firecuda 2TB drive and had some unanswered questions I'd like confirmed.

1. What actually happens to my files? Say if Windows becomes used by the SSD part then will that delete my Windows files and put them on the SSD? Or would it copy them? Since I'm quite a paranoid person, I wouldn't like the SSD to suddenly fail and suddenly be unable to get it to boot.

Comment: If the SSD part fails, you probably will not have access to any part of the drive even if the files were on the HD section and vice versa.  You could probably have it recovered though but YOU would not be able to "get it to boot" probably by any "normal" means.

Comment: I saw in many other forums that if the SSD part fails then its continued to exist like a HDD.

Comment: "Probably" is the operative word.  There is no standard for these things.  You are at the whim of the manufacturer.  If you plan on not having access upon SSD failure, and then you do, it is a good day.  If it goes the other way.  well.....

Comment: A single drive is a point of failure anyway - have backups, no matter what.

Comment: Not everyone has enough spare money to grab another large drive. I'm in college right now so I don't exactly have a huge income.

Answer (score 0):

While I can only confirm this based on experience, the SSD and mechanical portion of the disk cannot operate without each other, therefore a failure in one renders the entire drive inoperable.

Note that the SSHD drive decides what data to put on the SSD *at the block level*. The drive isn't aware of the higher level file system in use, so even if you could "recover" data from the SSD portion of the disk, it's unlikely it would be useful data.

Comment: Could I recover the HDD partition as usual though? According to a site called hetmanrecovery it says that its possible to do so. Obviously your are replying via experience but I just wondered if you had any other knowledge on the subject. Thanks.

Comment: @James If the drive continues to function such that *any* recovery efforts are possible, then yes, recovery would be possible. Keep in mind being able to *attempt* recovery doesn't mean what you get off the drive is good data.

Comment: So what are the chances of having recovery at all? Actually a better question I supposed would be what are chances of it getting to that stage? Since Its going to be brand new.

Comment: @James That's the wrong question. Any storage device can fail, no matter how reliable/resilient/redundant it is. There's never a reason to not have a backup. And backups make data recovery moot in all but the craziest of edge cases.

Comment: In other words, if you're concerned you might someday need to perform data recovery, make a backup so that you **don't have to**.

Comment: My old HDD will still have most of my files still on it, so I won't be going too far back if anything happens. Is there a way to check if an SSHD is going to fail? (since SMART doesn't work for SSD right?)

Comment: SMART works fine with SSD/SSHDs. It can predict failures that are predictable. Not all are. I had an SSHD die 2 days after installation, and then another 6 months after install. Neither gave predictive failure warning.

Comment: Thanks for the help, ill have to see when I install it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a 2TB version of this drive fail on me. I took it to a data recovery center and after 3 days, they nor the recovery hardware vendor could access it. They said that unlike a regular drive, the firmware is recreated each time on the SSD and therefore is different each time....so no board swap out and no joy :-( The I'll keep the drive, because we all know the future changes things ;-)